# Splash screen runs then flashes the wrong random image before application starts

Tags: ios, cordova, splash-screen

Not sure how to word this problem, but basically it lodes the flash screen for half a second (like I want - look at first image).

Then it flashes the splash screen upside down at the bottom of the screen just before loading the app. (look at second image).

How can I get rid of it displaying the second upside down image?

I am using Xcode 4.6.3 with Cordova 2.9.0.

[image: Working splash screen]

I want to get rid of the image below from appearing:

[image: flash]

Comment: Is this behavior in landscape mode only?

Comment: Yes, I have changed the supported interface orientations for the iPhone to "Landscape left" only. It works fine on the iPad.. it just happens on the iPhone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Xp9nT-b9dA

I needed the `Initial interface orientation = Landscape (left home button)` under the project info section.

I think it must have been loading the image for portrait then rotated it to try and make it match the landscape orientation therefore rotating the image.