# PhoneGap + Landscape: SplashScreen Loads Properly, Then Rotates Briefly Before Flashing and Disappearing

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cordova, splash-screen

I'm working on an iPhone app designed to only use Landscape orientation (PhoneGap 3.0, Xcode 4.6.3). I've included the appropriately sized launch images in Xcode, and have specified only the iPhone as the target device, and have only enabled Landscape Left and Landscape Right.

I have a splash-screen image which I'm also using as a background image on the first page of my app. My intended goal is for there to be a seamless/invisible transition from the splash-screen to the first page of my app (where all that happens is a button, fading in).

This is working, but after the splash-screen loads... after a moment, the splash-screen image (not sure if it's the same one) rotates and is misaligned/zoomed in. This then disappears, and we arrive at the first page of my app.

Here's a side by side - on the left is the splash-screen, and on the right is what happens when the splash-screen rotates briefly.

[image: Left: splash-screen with button. Right: splash-screen briefly rotated]

I also made a video of what happens when I try to launch the app. You can see the rotation/flicker [here on this YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gFNVeay8a0w).

I installed the splash-screen plugin, thinking that that might give me more control over this issue. In the outermost config.xml file, I updated this line:

`<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />`

and set the value to **false**.

When I did this, the splash-screen displayed properly initially, but when it rotated... it "froze" in place, along with a spinner. This behavior is visible in the [second half of the same video](http://youtu.be/gFNVeay8a0w?t=6s).

I would like to remove this splash-screen rotation, and it feels like I'm overlooking something fairly basic. The fact that the splash-screen plugin amplifies the effect suggests to me that this may be an Xcode setting somewhere?

Not sure the best way to go about trying to troubleshoot this issue. The more I'm looking at it, the less certain I am of whether it's a PhoneGap or Xcode issue. Any help or advice greatly appreciated, as I've spent a great deal of time trying to suss this out.

I've seen a few other questions that are similar to mine, but so far no definitive answer as to what might be causing this. Some of the older answers, though the issue descriptions are very similar, reference code I can no longer locate.

[Splash screen runs then flashes the wrong random image before application starts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530013/splash-screen-runs-then-flashes-the-wrong-random-image-before-application-starts)
[iPhone 5 splashscreen not displaying correctly - Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450603/iphone-5-splashscreen-not-displaying-correctly-phonegap)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I handled this. The fix unfortunately adds resources to your project, but doesn't show the white flicker or rotated background image.

The first image you are seeing is Xcode's rendering of the splash screen which is at the correct orientation. The few seconds of rotation is PhoneGap's rendering, and that is where the problem is, in the file CDVSplashScreen.m. I'm not familiar enough with Objective-C or Cordova's code to rewrite this plugin, but as a fix, I did the following:

(1) Duplicate all your screen images and rename them by adding Cordova to the beginning of the file. So for example, you'll have Default.png and CordovaDefault.png. For all the new Cordova-named images, make them the solid background color (or in my case, pattern) of your original background images.

(2) Open CDVSplashScreen.m and find the lines:

```
    if (imageName) {
        imageName = [imageName stringByDeletingPathExtension];
        } else {
        imageName = @"Default";
        }
```

For the version I have, this is line 126. Replace the lines with:

```
    imageName = @"CordovaDefault";
```

What this is doing is telling PhoneGap to use the new images, and leaving the original images for Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the launch image that was appearing and being rotated was *Default~iphone.png*.

In some additional testing, I found that in the outermost config.xml file, I was able to remove this rotated splash screen instance by modifying the following code

```
    <feature name="SplashScreen">
            <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSplashScreen" />
            <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
```

and setting the *onload* param to a value of **false**. That seemed to do the trick.

I'm now seeing a white "flash" between the splash screen and the first page of my app, but I've seen several questions related to that here... so it feels like progress.

// Edit: I believe the rotated splash image is actually PhoneGap's splash-screen (and that the splash-screen plugin was designed to handle the white "flash/flicker" issue others have reported). Not sure why it's handling the *Default~iphone.png* launch image in this manner, when the app is set to be Landscape only.

Comment: Looks like this may be a known issue:  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-3562